# Android проблема с подключением к локальному серверу

Tags: android

Пишу приложение на Android.

Способ взаимодействия: REST API.

Сервер: Локальный сервер WampServer

Проблема: отсутствие подключения.
Пытаюсь подключиться к API, но никак не получается:

Код:

```
public class ApiUtils {
//    private static String apiUrl = "https://localhost/usatu/";
//    private static String apiUrl = "https://192.168.0.102/usatu/";
 //   private static String apiUrl = "https://192.168.0.1/usatu/";
      private static String apiUrl = "https://10.0.3.2/"
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static APIService api;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){

        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(apiUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }


    public static APIService getApi(){
        if(api == null){
            api = getRetrofit().create(APIService.class);
        }
        return api;
    }
}
```

Никак не могу подключиться к серверу:
Traceback:

```
W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Failed to connect to /192.168.0.1:443
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onError(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:47)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:79)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.0.1:443
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:248)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2779)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
        at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.1 (port 443) from /192.168.234.231 (port 55154) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:273)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
        ... 33 more
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:262)
        ... 43 more
```

Хотя если я через браузер обращусь к серверу по `http://localhost/usatu/v1/semesters` возвращается правильный результат.

ip определил с помощью команды ipconfig (window)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тестирую на эмуляторе Genymotion

**Update**:
Через браузер на эмуляторе подключился по адресу `htttp://10.0.3.2/v1/semesters`
и он там работает, но ошибка в приложении не исчезает

**API:**

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("v1/semesters")
    Single<List<Semester>> getSemesters();
}
```

**Presenter:**

```
@InjectViewState
public class SearchScheduleStudentPresenter extends BasePresenter<SearchScheduleStudentView> {

    private SearchScheduleStudentView mView;

    public SearchScheduleStudentPresenter(SearchScheduleStudentView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    public void getSemesters(){
        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                ApiUtils.getApi()
                .getSemesters()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        response -> mView.showSemesters(response)
                )
        );


    }
}
```

**View**

```
public interface SearchScheduleStudentView extends BaseView {

    void showSemesters(List<Semester> semesters);

}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void showSemesters(List<Semester> semesters) {
        List<String> semestersName = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Semester semester : semesters) {
            semestersName.add(semester.getName());

        }
//        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, semestersName);
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Проверка работы** на эмуляторе в браузере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623872/failed-to-connect-to-localhost-127-0-0-1-android

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko не помогло, указал port apache (80) в genymotion, но нет

Comment: Вам нужен адрес компьютера в WiFi сети, где крутится сервер, это явно не https://192.168.0.1. Возможно у вас эмулятор не в этой сети и потому не видит `https://192.168.0.102`

Comment: адрес компьютера в сети https://192.168.0.102, но с ним как видите не работает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб посмотрите обновление

Comment: @danilshik, возможно дело в эмуляторе. Вы пробовали стандартный эмулятор или реальный девайс?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб падает и на встроенной в Android Studio и на реальном

Comment: А вы пробовали устанавливать в качестве адреса API то что у вас в вопросе указано (htttp://10.0.3.2) - вы туда через браузер эмулятора ходили и оно работает. Просто в коде в вопросе у вас сейчас адрес, кажется, роутера, а не сервера.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну соответственно, я просто код не менял

Comment: Т.е. адрес таки используете тот же, что и в браузере на эмуляторе работает? Если так, то может у вас просто разрешения на интернет в манифесте нет?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну если бы в manifest не было permission другая бы ошибка была бы, и да адрес тот же использую что и в браузере эмулятора. Обновил код

Comment: Возможно проблема на сервере. Посмотрите его логи в момент коннекта - может там что-то полезное есть

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну а какая разница, мы же все равно к этой странице обращаемся?

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в логах Apache ошибок: последняя дата 12 апреля

Comment: Логи доступа: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2019:21:04:32 +0300] "GET /v1/semesters HTTP/1.1" 200 265, статус 200, значит все норм

Comment: На скрине у вас сервер в браузере открытый... Надо бы логи именно сервера глянуть когда вы из андроида обращаетесь. Плюс проверьте что ошибка не в Retrofit (его использовании) - попробуйте просто через OkHttp запрос на сервер послать из андроида..

Comment: @ЮрийСпб нашел ошибку. Как всегда, самая дурацкая)

Comment: И что же была за ошибка? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСпб ошибка в протоколе, не тот написал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я вместо http указал https.

Можно использовать как ip компьютера в сети (в моем случае, это 192.168.0.102), так и 
10.0.3.2 (постоянный), который был добавлен в Genymotion, начиная с версии 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Выглядит так, что Вы пытаетесь подключиться, используя IP роутера, а не Вашего компьютера. Попробуйте раскомментировать адрес `192.168.0.102`.

Подробнее об интерпретации вывода команды `ipconfig` можно прочитать, например, [здесь](https://zametkinapolyah.ru/zametki-o-poleznyx-programmax/komanda-ipconfig-v-windows.html).

Comment: я как бы все попробовал уже

Comment: Если Вы расширите вопрос информацией о конфигурации сервера и сети, возможно будет проще дать ответ.

Comment: ноутбук подключен к интернету по средством wifi. IP компьютера: 192.168.0.102. Подключаюсь с эмулятора genymotion, запущенного с этого же компьютера

Comment: Тогда может быть полезным посмотреть настройки сети на эмеляторе [[1](https://docs.genymotion.com/latest/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Managing_virtual_devices/Configuring_a_virtual_device.htm), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075796/genymotion-emulator-no-internet-connection)].

Comment: @ПетрВытовтов вы скинули инструкцию по подключению к интернету, у меня с этим проблем нет, эмулятор прекрасно работает с интернетом, он не видит локальный сервер